# Api config typing with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to strogly type backend handling, but having a problem with how generics interact with `...args`.

Below is the code example with declaration and 2 use cases. Only difference between cases is that config type is set explicitly in first case.

### The problem

- in first case - config typing is **good**, but instance typing is **lacking**.
- in second case - config typing is **lacking**, but instance typing is **good**.

Ideally I want to have **good** typing in both config and service.

I tried `Parameters<typeof someFunction>`, and it works without issues, only with generics it fails sometimes.

Check [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKj4iAIBEFEDCAZAggJRQFQJIHkByUkxJIwAUOQJYB2ALgKYBOAZgIYDGDUcNAJgAcA9rToIhNFlQDmUAN7koUWgC4oACgB02tk2kBnNWxoBPAJRQAvAD4oANxF9FUIQFc6a9XbYAbVwzUAcg4hJiYGDjpAixt7R3IAX3I6EwFuXkERenFJGX0rKDQI0L4AHn06JlppABoefmFRHKlpa0oOHzZ9fJQBKgBlZjsqLlK4fBgABVxsfEwAfQQCADFsAHF%20qAYAD0Z%20fIzG7IkW-VsFJRCaCqZXSND1KAFXACMfEa2GrLETvLVxqYzOaLFbrTYWORJZwML6iKBjCbTWaYLa7GF8fIAawYJiELB4iKBCyW%20FWG2s6nRRw8BMByLMal6VEO3wRdOBJLJ-TqAKRc3OziU4ToriYNCgNAYAHcoEyWaJHlTvlAzM4klCOl0en15fQ2XziaCNqi9hj6pkmr8DDzCciTeisTi8bSDSDSWCBZcJDc7nQHk9Xu8OJ8LfR-ra5ir5FClF0TDRg7dxVodHpDFBJro2ABbBiMJj6fVEt1cgDavKJAF1S4FaIFK9YGRmmEJs1R9AxSsYTOd1ZRgMAoJgABbcCQ%20ExQPhUFgsZgwrhQF55qUMGFQABMUA4XQY%20XbqIEQaodCgKT6NFkzoABrqfrkDNfNP3SMQoAgUP04FAAIxEV%20vhQ5BXBUIbUs0eQ-v8sLHA%20%20SWPIziMBUd5qBcSjKDQnjeH4ARQMEoThJE0RWL2NSCi47jYb4-gxOc9g0QwADUTFQAkUADvCAC076tkebC0Pko7hJoUAAOrDiMw7KPkIRhBEdDPko6oANztN6p5sH0gxMMMXDYNcdDGFwf4IZKMpMjpekMJSMH3qcP6qiBp7IXQd6mVAWkDEMIwMAZFTGQwP6aEqCqBK5d7RMke5uXZwVJuogRSi2l4kZxpQ8TAQh7jQ4XbnxnS0FAwkMKJElSTJUD4LgKJSsObCnquUBSsYimUOQoAAeA76ft%20W5daQQHOWB3wQQYW4IehEV2WhFGqBoOH%20EEclEVEdH4clEjSIE5EYZRNJeIx61yAxuEsWxHGDhlp3%20JVIFUHw858FA17dtexXzmVkkcNJB7VbV9WNdwLX0EpbGJGpwEaZ52k%20fphmBRNErSrKsO6b5tmhvZeQbk50PTVjSNeVZvn%20UZCYMBuIV2YlBPUlFdPfFTCVJSl20WOlPHiNm-GCR94R1HVFUHnVDXNcDrXPh1g7YI9vgTlA2DNa1Z5CMVbB2Nw57VJhS5CHQ0k7h2%20jPpx2D4rirhPFqUD6K23D6FQPM%20NwLCuAmdBUBIqsZlmub5oW54MM6ltMMs7uRF7NC2DxJ7NaEmL5AAVq4oFSJKpuDgAQu4zUntJ0gwswIz5LHp58Nl%20i5aePEsKEtv21A4RdBIz5AA) so you can see how it works (you can hover to check types etc). TS version is `4.1.3`.

And thanks for any help in advance.

```js
/************** DECLARATION ******************/

interface EndpointConfig {
  in: (...args: any) => void
  out: (value: 'correct') => void
}
type EndpointConfigs = Record<string, EndpointConfig>

class ApiService<ENDPOINT_CONFIGS extends EndpointConfigs> {
  constructor( public endpointConfigs: ENDPOINT_CONFIGS ) {}

  endpoint <ENDPOINT extends keyof ENDPOINT_CONFIGS>(endpoint: ENDPOINT): ApiEndpoint<ENDPOINT_CONFIGS, ENDPOINT> {
    return new ApiEndpoint( endpoint )
  }
}

class ApiEndpoint<ENDPOINT_CONFIGS extends EndpointConfigs, ENDPOINT extends keyof ENDPOINT_CONFIGS> {
  constructor( public endpoint: ENDPOINT ) {}

  async run (...args: Parameters<ENDPOINT_CONFIGS[ENDPOINT]['in']>): Promise<any> {}
}

/************** CASE 1 *******************/

const endpointConfigs1: EndpointConfigs = {
  testEndpoint: {
    in: (value: 'correct') => {},
    out: (value) => { value++ } // <- Complains here. Which is correct.
  }
};

const apiServiceInstance1 = new ApiService(endpointConfigs1)
const testEndpoint1 = apiServiceInstance1.endpoint('testEndpoint')
testEndpoint1.run('wrong') // <- Doesn't complain here. Which is NOT what we want.


/************** CASE 2 *******************/

const endpointConfigs2 = {
  testEndpoint: {
    in: (value: 'correct') => 'wrong',
    out: (value) => { value++ } // <- value is considered `any` here. Which is NOT what we want.
  }
};

const apiServiceInstance2 = new ApiService(endpointConfigs2)
const testEndpoint2 = apiServiceInstance2.endpoint('testEndpoint')
testEndpoint2.run('wrong') // <- Complains here, which is what we want.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a little trick to get TS to infer some types. Here's a minimal working example that can be applied in a variety of contexts:

```
const trick = <K extends string>(k: K) => k
// has type "test"
const test = trick("test")
```

Let's see how we can apply it in your Context ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIgCYAcD2owDCOIMwA5gDwCCUZAzshAB6SYNwgCeA2gLoB8yAN4AoZMlAAuZAAoAdAri060mvQCUyALyCAbngxjkOAK5hpM3XAA2JiNIDkCHFCgQEYB5p3J9wQwC+IsFgnFgoRCTkACLu1kpwYMDEFAAKjCwQbMgASu4uGBR0YFCgZAA0yBw8AoJawkbi3ADWEiDIzRCcODDIqbzS6Nh44JGklKktAiJBIWEoAJIgACrzFAQwZBmsGAxDuPhj5BTV-HVGG1vMO3uYB6PE4xSgMNDIanT8jcgA-O-K32kl2CIgA9KDkMsABbABiwqrIErABCtMA4NqvKCIqEoZyudxgRHzORgiELbGgVE45DOAC2WGA1jedChpmsGERcE6NKUKB62JQUBM4GAtL5umgOLghmcIGKiNKKO0yDS2yyu1y+SghWKpRAFSqXD4ZxkRgwcQSSWIQMeMQtUESyRAaS+4nUNqiZFiCHiDqtztSdVd4mQ5p9lqdIPByAAEtAIJUAO4oOBYLDWTgChXI5oiWXy9X3Qi2+jKpEomSicSQYr7EbmBohtoWKy2ezIABEeLcHg73kEDkTUGIZAc5W+0ehKFC4WMvQABq27POJHCSNA3By4GudhAMCSm6YG0uUD4hOIAsgjEEAuooxCp0TZ-Dt21d4YZyhlhB5fUq8gWjaDoun5T9+ULesjnoAZkCWVZwgoMDeggw4SzoKYvlmPN4joBgqAZABlaBdGRCAKGiNVsig71fUdFJTkEf98xKEwPBcGRkCwEwACNrGRRg7kgtDpAozQhFmcQUPAFVUAAOWiVIAHkFlk5ZKI1Tpul6aJ+BkKSGzkhTlNU913gZOt8HIypDKUlTlkY743DAEwoHaEAIETMzgAs8AOP05A7wvGYQXDXCvJ8sByPUhhqPtOjnVOaz5Ns1TouArTkB0xsaWIXVWLRKAOK43j+P0wZkuMtSxIkqo6E4EAEGQIV2nkRRlGkOC1mibgbMqgRTNSYdaVhMjTmEG8QtywlU2AIioBIpAlmKDgkAAJmVdzPPw2biNIvTBNQz06DvZjER-MAIvW+oZrmhaICWsAVogVa5H0mQHBrC6DvALwQU+y65Ga96hxHLxkGjCgAFpkCIel4lABgcTcJMYQQKFV2QRMoUSTGUETDgwBJf7vrAF6ga7FwezAPsgA)):

```
interface EndpointConfig<Args extends any[]> {
  in: (...args: Args) => void
  out: (value: 'correct') => void
}


type ConfigDeclaration<P extends Record<string, any[]>> = {
    [k in keyof P]: EndpointConfig<P[k]>
}


type InType<Cfg extends EndpointConfig<any>> =
  Cfg extends EndpointConfig<infer Args>
    ? Args
    : never


// This is a trick to infer the correct type.
// I think the JIT compiler should take care of the runtime overhead
const trick = <P extends Record<string, any[]>>(
  declaration: ConfigDeclaration<P>
  ): ConfigDeclaration<P> =>
    declaration


// Here, we apply the trick
const endpointConfigs = trick({
  testEndpoint: {
    in: (value: "correct") => 'wrong',
    // The type of `value` is inferred as intended.
    out: value => {  } 
  }
})


// The type is as intended
type Test = {
  [k in keyof typeof endpointConfigs]: InType<typeof endpointConfigs[k]>
}


class ApiService<D extends ConfigDeclaration<any>> {
  constructor( public endpointConfigs: D ) {}

  endpoint <ENDPOINT extends keyof D>(endpoint: ENDPOINT): ApiEndpoint<D, ENDPOINT> {
    return new ApiEndpoint( endpoint )
  }
}


class ApiEndpoint<D extends ConfigDeclaration<any>, ENDPOINT extends keyof D> {
  constructor( public endpoint: ENDPOINT ) {}

  async run (...args: InType<D[ENDPOINT]>): Promise<any> {}
}


const apiServiceInstance2 = new ApiService(endpointConfigs)
const testEndpoint2 = apiServiceInstance2.endpoint('testEndpoint')


testEndpoint2.run('wrong') // <- Complains here, which is what we want.
testEndpoint2.run("correct")
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!
Did you figure the trick on your own, or is that condensed in some doc I missed. If yes, link would be awesome, as I don't really understand what's going on.

Comment: I usually follow the TS roadmap (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) to stay up to date with new features. And I learned a lot from reading/asking questions here.